# REGEX Find the string between 2 strings

Tags: notepad++, regex, perl

In the example below, I want to use regex as to find the html tag `<sony>` between other 2 lines.

```
         <table width="697" border="0">
      <tr>
        <td><h1 class="den_articol" itemprop="name">Your Mirror</h1></td>
      </tr>
        </table>
<sony>
<p class="text_obisnuit"><span class="text_obisnuit2">* Not&#259;:</span> <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IB4P5t3JGlg" target="_new">Simply Red - Your Mirror</a></p>
```

**The OUTPUT:**

`<sony>`

**My regex formula doesn't work:**

`</table>\s+\n(.*?)<p class="text_obisnuit">`

Comment: Just remove `\s+` from your regex as it seems there're no spaces after `</table>`.

Comment: yes, but in this case will select all  those       `</table>
<sony>
<p class="text_obisnuit">` . And I want only `<sony>`

Comment: Yes, it will. But what are you trying to do? Do you want to remove everything except `<sony>`? Find: `\A[\s\S]+</table>\s+(\S+)\s+<p class="text_obisnuit">[\s\S]+\z` and replace with: `$1`

Comment: please put your solution in an ANSWER !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can give a solution for the case where there are not a variable number
of spaces following `<table>`, because I use look-behind that does not
support this in order to test without capturing.

My regex :

```
(?<=<\/table>\n)(.*?)\n(?=<p class="text_obisnuit">)
```

You may see it in action on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/wIYXDw/1).

Don't forget in Notepad++ to check the option of ". matches newline".

Some explanation :

| Lookaround | Name | What it Does |
| --- | --- | --- |
| (?=foo) | Lookahead | Asserts that what immediately FOLLOWS the current position in the string is foo |
| (?<=foo) | Lookbehind | Asserts that what immediately PRECEDES the current position in the string is foo |

[image]

Answer (score 2):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\A[\s\S]+</table>\s+(\S+)\s+<p class="text_obisnuit">[\s\S]+\z`
- Replace with: `$1`
- **TICK** *Wrap around*
- **SELECT** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\A                          # beginning of file
[\s\S]+                     # 1 or more any character
</table>                    # literally
\s+                         # 1 or more any spaces
(\S+)                       # group 1, 1 or more any character that is not a space
\s+                         # 1 or more any spaces
<p class="text_obisnuit">   # literally
[\s\S]+                     # 1 or more any character
\z                          # end of file
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Another solution:**

**FIND:** `(?s)(?-i:<!-- ARTICOL START -->|(?!\A)\G).*?\K(?<=</table>\s)(.*?)(?=\s<p class="text_obisnuit">)(?!<!-- ARTICOL FINAL -->)`

**Next time Use this GENERIC FORMULA:**

`(?s)(?-i:BSR|(?!\A)\G).*?\K(?<=FR1)(.*?)(?=FR2)(?!ESR)`

**BSR =**  `<!-- ARTICOL START -->`

**FR1 =** `</table>\s`

**FR2 =** `\s<p class="text_obisnuit">`

**ESR =** `<!-- ARTICOL FINAL -->`

Let BSR ( Begin Search-region Regex ) be the regex which defines the beginning of the area where the search for FR, must start

Let ESR ( End Search-region Regex) be the regex which defines, implicitly, the area where the search for FR, must end

Let FR (Find Regex ) be the regex which defines the char, string or expression to be searched

Let RR (Replacement Regex ) be the regex which defines the char, string or expression which must replace the FR expression. REPLACE RR (means can be \1 \2 ...or $1 $2 or other

Answer (score 0):

**I find myself a solution:**

**FIND:** `</table>\r\n\K<.*?>|(?s)\R\R(?=<p class="text_obisnuit">)`